# PHP PDO error handling halting execution

Tags: php, ajax, pdo, error-handling

I am pretty new to PHP, coming from ASP, and am having a hard time understanding exactly how error handling works with PHP and PDO.  Here is what I have going on...

PDO is set with:

```
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
```

I am making an AJAX call to a PHP page to process some data and save it to MySQL using PDO.  I have my DB scripts in a try catch like so:

```
function processStuff(){
    try {
       $sth = $db->prepare( query );
       $sth->execute();
    } catch (PDOEXCEPTION $e){
        //log error
    }

    //if no error
    return array(some json);
}
```

let's say something bad happens and I get an error like:

```
Error: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'field' cannot be null' in C:\filepath:202
```

What is happening is that the error is halting the script, thereby causing the calling page to just hang.  The AJAX is waiting for a JSON reponse that will tell whether it succeeded or failed.  But because it is hanging, it doesn't get the response, so I don't have the opportunity to show the user there was an error.

I also have a custom error handler function:

```
function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    //log errors
}

set_error_handler("errorHandler")
```

that can log errors.  But, due to my newbieness, I am not sure how to use that in the try/catch.

So my question is, how do I log an error when a PDO exception occurs and make sure that the script continues processing so that the calling page with the AJAX doesn't hang.

All the other answers around similar questions assume a level of knowledge that I don't seem to have yet.  I am not clear if I am supposed to throw an error to be caught, or if it is automatically being thrown.  If PDO is automatically throwing it, how do I call my error handler in the catch?  would I just use:

```
errorHandler();
```

And if I switched to ERRMODE_SILENT, which I believe would continue the processing, how do I detect the error in order to throw it to the catch?

I am sure there are some basic concepts that I am just not understanding about how this works. Code is great, but any explanation is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

UPDATE:
Here is the actual try block:

```
        try {
            $sth = $dbh->prepare ("INSERT INTO email_validation (email, val_code) VALUES (:a1, :a2)");
            $sth->bindParam (":a1", $email);
            $sth->bindParam (":a2", $gencode);
            $sth->execute ();
        } catch (PDOEXCEPTION $e) {
            $err = true;
            $errmsg = date("F j, Y, g:i a") . "\n" . ERR_URL . "\n" . $e . "\n\n";
            error_log($errmsg,3,ERR_LOG_PATH_INT);
        }
```

The AJAX looks like this:

```
    $.post('Functions/AJAX-new-account.php', $('form').serialize(), function(data) {
        var c = data.check;
        if(c==1){
            //process client side stuff here
        }else{
            //----Ooops there was an error-----//
            //show error to client
        };
        return false;
    },"json");
```

I guess the JSON is getting written, but I am not understanding why I am not appearing to get to }else{ in my AJAX and the page appears to be stalled.

ANOTHER UPDATE:  so I just tried

```
trigger_error("blah blah");
```

in the catch block and it stopped hanging.  The errorHandler seems to have processed the error correctly, although my AJAX processed it incorrectly, but it did stop hanging.  Is this a correct way to handle this, or is there a better way?

Comment: The processing should continue just fine, since you've caught the exception. Can you show the actual code, including what's in the `catch` block?

Comment: So you are calling an AJAX page and the error is occurring in the ajax page?  Your issue is that the AJAX response isn't sending back an error message?  Put a return in your catch that has the error message, and then "catch" that with the jquery ajax call.  If the json is a fail event, then display the message.

Comment: An AJAX (XHR) response most certainly *is* being sent, even if not with an HTTP 200 status code (if not then it means the PHP process/code is never terminating and the HTTP channel is never closed, which is doubtful!). This can be *trivially verified* by looking at the Network tab of the browser tools. Make sure to *also* handle the `fail`ing case (for "bad JSON" and/or a non-200 response) in JavaScript/jQuery/XHR.

Comment: I am getting a 200 response when the error occurs.  I am not sure how to handle the failing case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got several questions in here, and I'll try to answer them all.

> If I switched to ERRMODE_SILENT, which I believe would continue the processing, how do I detect the error in order to throw it to the catch?

Instead of using try/catch in this case, you'd need an `if` statement checking the PDO error code, e.g. `if ($db->errorCode() !== null)` (see PHPDoc for [PDO Error Handling](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)) where you would log the error, perhaps set the [HTTP Response Code](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) to something you expect from Javascript.

> Why is my AJAX request hanging after this failure?

I'd suspect that your page is not actually hanging; rather, no JS is being executed for one reason or another. In your first attempts, you would be getting a 500 error code, which would not trigger the `.success()` function you provided to `$.post`. In order to see the problem in this case, you'd need to add a `.fail()` callback to your AJAX request.

Once you swapped to using `trigger_error`, a 200 OK would be returned since no exception was thrown. I'm not sure what you mean by "my AJAX processed it incorrectly".

> Is this a correct way to handle this, or is there a better way?

This depends a lot on preference. A PDO exception for me should be very rare because I'm processing and validating the data before I ever send it to the database. In your case, `Column 'field' cannot be null` is a good example of something you should check beforehand.

If a PDO exception does occur, I would try to handle it gracefully -- that means `catch`ing it, logging an error, setting the HTTP Response Code to something sensible (probably `400 Bad Request` would do), and returning a result with an error message. From the Javascript, I'd have a `.fail` method that parses the result for an error and displays something appropriate to the user. Having completely separate methods for success and failure cases is a good design principle and can help keep clutter from your code.

I hope this helps you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks xanthien, that gives me a good place to start. A question...  So using the SILENT case, I would get rid of the try/catch all together  and do something like:  if($db->errorCode() !== null){trigger_error();}  in order to log the error?

Comment: Precisely. It'd look something like "if ($sth->errorCode() !== null) { trigger_error('Unexpected exception from PDO! Message: ' . print_r($sth->errorInfo()), E_USER_ERROR); }" Though I'd probably prefer to keep it on ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, as the Exception comes with a convenient '$ex->getMessage()' that has a nicely-formatted error message already, and a try/catch is more explicit for error conditions than an if() statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.  I think this will definitely get me where I need to go.